# Javascript jScrollPane rendering but not scrolling?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, scroll, jscrollpane

My site has been using jscrollpane [ http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ ] for my rails apps and it's been fine.

Someone reported that the scrolling is not working in the app anymore, and I'm not sure when this started happening and can't trace it to a particular commit which is frustrating.

I made a demo page to show: https://www.vvx.io/scrollpane

- the scrollpane seems to initialise but as you can see is 'unscrollable' - I thought/think it might be an ordering issue, etc. or some sort of conflict, but I cannot figure out what the issue is despite trying numerous things.

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue and/or have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting from jquery 1.8 to 1.7.2 fixed this.